# running pentaho 404 ressource not available

Tags: pentaho

I am trying to run pentaho server on the browser on this adress : http://localhost:8080/pentaho/home , i am getting http 404 the requested resource is not available. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be try this. The below URL is for logging in

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho-di/Login
```